# Nested if/else statements in Lua - Corona SDK

Tags: if-statement, lua, nested, coronasdk

Trying to make movement halt when (x) key is lifted (w,a,s,d) however I do not want the movement to stop if another key is held down. This is the snippet of code I was trying to use which was not working:

```
  if (event.keyName == 'w' and event.phase == 'up') then
    if (event.keyName == 's' and event.phase == 'down') then
      testObj.deltaPerFrame = {testObj.deltaPerFrame[1], 2 }
    else
      testObj.deltaPerFrame = {testObj.deltaPerFrame[1], 0 }
      return true
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the same key event object so event.keyName or event.phase cannot have two different values. Hence your condition doesn't make any sense.

Please refer to the CoronaSDK manual.

https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/key/keyName.html

You'll have to maintain a list of keys that are currently pressed.